# How to spread divs containing images horizontally with even spacing?

Tags: html, css, spacing

The header of my site is some text and a logo. The font used isnt standard so the text is image based.

I want the elements of the site to change with the size of the browser window. I believe this is called fluid design?

So I want the text and logo in the header to scale and be evenly spaced horizontally. There are 5 letters, then the logo, then 5 more letters. One more curveball, I want the logo to be dead center of the page at all times.

I've looked around and it seems there are multiple ways out there to do this. And all have their own caveats based on ever evolving functionality of html and css, I'm guessing more css than html.

So what would be the best way to do this as of June 8 2014? =P Obviously I want it to work in as many browsers as possible.

Comment: yes you can use media queries as Jere said, or you can use percents and em in defining your widths (to serve the same page style on all device sizes). Just keep researching and post back with what you've done so we can give a more specific answer.

Comment: When you say image-based text of 5 letters, are you talking about 1 image of 5 letters or 5 images each with one letter?

Comment: @Marc- Well total it would be 11 images. 10 containing a letter and 1 containing a logo.

Comment: Within the parent container enclosing the images, how are the first and the last images to be positioned?

Comment: @ Marc - I'm thinking the furthest left and right image would butt up right to the border of the div.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to change your content depending on the screen size:

### 1. Use percents

If you have some elements which should change their size whenever the user changes the screensize, I would recommend using percents.

```
.content {
   width: 90%;
   height: 50%;
}
```

In this example the class `.content` will have always a height of 50% and a width of 90% - it will change its pixel-size whenever the user changes the screensize. You can create a very flexible layout with that.

### 2. @media-querys

If you want to change something more than sizes, you have a static layout or want to create something like a mobile version, css has a @media-query:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .content {
         background-color: red;
    }
}
```

If the screen-width is between 600px and 1000px the background-color of `.content` will change to red. Just put the changes you want the header to do into a @media-query like this and it will work perfectly.

You'll find a very good noob-tutorial for @media-queries at [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I hope this is what you meant with your description of having your logo/type in center of page. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt6frey/7SZtg/) I made for the solution.

here's the code

**HTML:**

```
<header>
  <div id="wrap">
      <div id="container">
      <div id="logo"><img src="http://mattfrey.ca/img/springfarm/sf-preview2.jpg" alt="sample image"></div>
      <div id="fiveLets">F&nbsp;I&nbsp;V&nbsp;E&nbsp;R</div>
      <div class="clearFix"></div>
         </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header { width:100%; padding:0; margin:0; }
img { height: auto; max-width: 100%; padding: 0;}
#wrap { width:80%; margin:0 auto; outline: solid 1px red; background-color:#ccc;}
#container { margin: 0 auto; width:50%; background-color:#fff; outline: solid 1px blue;}
#logo { width:49%;}
#logo img { background-color: blue; float: left; }
#fiveLets { font-size: 2em; margin-top: 1.35em; float: right; margin-left: 1%; width:49%; }
.clearFix {clear:both}

/*responsive changes*/
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #fiveLets { font-size: 1em; } /*shrink text*/
    #wrap { background-color: #666; }
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) { /*doesn't seem to respond--jsfiddle*/
    #fiveLets { font-size: 0.75em; }
    #wrap { background-color: #333; }
}
}
```

1) You have your header, logo and type.

2) the *#container* brings both elements (logo and type, both of which are floated) closer together, and is also centered to solve that issue.

3) when you adjust the browser width, the css for the *#logo img* will adjust automatically, but the type, you need to add some responsive css, using media queries.

The *jsfiddle* doesn't seem to shrink down to 300px, so you will have to test in your own browser.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking a shot at it. Not exactly what I'm looking for though. Let me try to explain it again, I know it's kind of confusing.

In the header there will be 11 images. 10 images that are 1 letter and in the middle of the letter images will be a logo. I would like to have all the images spread out horizontally and evenly spaced from one end of the div to the other. And preferably the logo image would always be dead center of the browser window.

Not too much to ask for right? =P

Comment: Okay so to reiterate what you are saying: out of the 11 images, the 6th image would be your logo and the type would be on either side all spaced evenly?

Comment: I am going to create another jsfiddle of another interpretation of what I understand what you want. See if I can get this right for you

Comment: "Okay so to reiterate what you are saying: out of the 11 images, the 6th image would be your logo and the type would be on either side all spaced evenly?"

Yep, you got it. Sorry, I didnt respond faster. Things have been hectic for me lately.

Comment: its all good . I was tied up myself. i will get something up for you soon. i just needed some clarification

Comment: Ok, dont worry about this issue. I ended up making one image that works and tweaked the CSS. Thanks for the help though.